# Create a dataframe with specific values fixed in a number of rows

Tags: r

How is it possible to have a dataframe and insert the same value in specific rows?

Example output:

```
data.frame(time = c("2011-01-14","2011-01-14","2011-01-14","2011-01-14","2011-01-28","2011-01-28")
```

For example here I want for the first four rows specific values and for the next two another specific one

Comment: data.frame(time = rep(c("2011-01-14","2011-01-28"),c(4,2))) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are putting a single vector inside a dataframe.
You can make a reference to a specific cell in several ways, let's say you have a dataframe called df:

```
df <- data.frame( time = c( rep("any data", times = 6)
```

There is a column called time, with the element "any data" six times on it.

In order to put specific values like your desired output, You need to refer to these cells and assign a desired value.

```
df[1:4,"time" ] <- "2011-01-14"
df[5:6,"time" ] <- "2011-01-28"
```

Check this useful pdf for more orientation on how this works:
https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/base-r.pdf